# Jquery Selector [name=”value”] selector don't work

Tags: jquery, google-tag-manager

I recently got all JQuery selector in the format 'Selector [name=”value”]' became 'Selector' in the browser.

so when writing this code in my js file

```
 $('div[data-product-id="'+key+'"] .price')
```

it Becames this in the browser =>

```
$('div .price')
```

Also for $('input[name="type"]') became $('input')

Comment: I write code like this  $('div[data-product-id="'+key+'"] .price') when inspecting the code in the browser it became $('div .price')

Comment: Save correctly your file or refresh your nav cache.

Comment: @Mohicane i did it but always i got this issue

Comment: Well... it almost sure that your javascript is not well deployed.

Try adding some console.log("something" in your javascript and look for it in the browser. If you don't find it, that it isn't the good javascript.

Comment: i tried console.log($('div[data-product-id="6672"] .price').html()); i got Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: Maybe you'll have to control the deployment of your js files. Check your if you can access to jquery and if it is declared BEFORE the script above. (Yes ... nearly one year later ... sorry)